# Understanding Instance Variables in Python

Tags: oop

I am slightly confused by the output of this program:

```
class Test(object):
    a = None
    b = None

    def __init__(self, a):
        print self.a
        self.a = a
        self._x = 123;
        self.__y = 123;
        b = 'meow'
```

The Outputs for the following lines are what confuse me:

```
instance = Test(3) #Output is None
print Test.a  #Output is None
print instance.a  #Output is 3. Why does this print 3?
```

I am struggling with why `print Instance.a` prints 3 and the other two lines don't.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
instance = Test(3) #Output is None
```

This is None, because you print `self.a` before it has been assigned.

```
print Test.a  #Output is None
```

This is None b because you are printing A in the Class, which hasn't been initialized yet so only the a = None of the class definition has been processed.

```
print instance.a  #Output is 3. Why does this print 3?
```

this prints 3, because you are calling it on the instance of the `Test` class that you created with the first call.  `__init__` has been run, and modified self.a to be the 3 that you provided (it is different from above since calling `Test.a`, the `__init__` method isn't called, so you get your assignment from the class definition

Answer (score 0):

Usually one write instances lowercase (i fixed it).

In order reading your program.

- entering init.

  - I should printing `self.a`:

    - Does the  current instance have an `a` attribute ? no.
    - Ok, look at the types, then.
    - Does the `Test` usually have a `a` attribute? Yes, it's `None`.
    - Ok, print `None`
  - set `self.a` to `3`.

    - Does this instance have `a` attribute? no.
    - ok create it and give it the value `3`.
- What the default `a` values for `Test` object ? it's None. Print it.
- What the value of `a` for this instance? it's 3.

Take a more human example.

Usually unamed people are named John Doe.

Someone unconscious enter an hospital at 8am. What's his name? (don't know, let's write "John Doe")

What's the name of the person that enter at 8 ? "John Doe"

He woke up, hey what's your name ? I'm `Bob`.

What's the name of the person that enter at 8 ? "Bob"

When someone unconscious enter the hospital, what's his name ? "John Doe" (didn't changed to "Bob")

If another patient enter and her Id is "Alice", what's her name ? Probably "Alice"